# Directory shows empty after hostpath mounting method in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

I am trying to mount a directory called rstudio which is residing in /mnt/rstudio. But when I try to mount using persistent volume, the directory is showing up but not the files inside rstudio. Here's my deployment file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rsp-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rsp
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rsp
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: testserver.local
      volumes:
       - name: rsp-persistent-storage
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: pv-claim-rsp
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: RSP_LICENSE
          value: MY LICENSE
        image: rstudio/rstudio-server-pro:latest
        name: rstudio-server-pro
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8787
        - containerPort: 5559
        volumeMounts:
         - name: rsp-persistent-storage
           mountPath: /tmp/rstudio
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rstudio-server-pro
spec:
  selector:
    app: rsp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: "8787"
    port: 8787
    targetPort: 8787
  type: NodePort
```

And my pv and pvc files are as follows

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-volume-rsp
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/rstudio"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-rsp
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Inside my /mnt/rstudio there are these much files.

```
[root@test-server rstudio]# ls
launcher.conf                      launcher-mounts          launcher.pub        rserver.conf  
launcher.kubernetes.conf           launcher-mounts_working  logging.conf        rsession.conf 
launcher.kubernetes.profiles.conf  launcher.pem             notifications.conf  r-versions
```

But after the pod is up and running, the directory is showing empty. Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to try defining `type: Directory` inside of `hostPath:` for your PV

Comment: It says we can't have type:Directory defined in the persistent volume file

Comment: i see, that means you PV should be `path: "/mnt/rstudio/"` - note `/` at the end :)

Comment: I added / . PV created. But still, it doesn't have files inside the folder rstudio.

Comment: when you dropped whole deployment - did you check that pvc is also gone?
like this `kubectl get pvc` and `kubectl get pv`. i've seen that pvc may be still there. so i would recommend drop everything. Make sure everything is gone including `pvc` and `pv`. then do change to pv and recreate everything back.

Comment: Yes, every time I try re-deploying, I used to delete all pv and pvc and run it again from scratch.

Comment: I reproduced your deployment with no issues. Are you sure you are checking `/tmp/rstudio` inside the pod and files are present on `testserver.local` node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LGTM. I am getting files if I swap the image with `nginx`. I would check two things:

1. Permissions: Check what permissions the files have. You may have to update your permissions or UID to access the files.
2. Does `rstudio` image use that path? It may be processing that folder when it starts. Try mounting to a different path and see if you can see the files.

Also, make sure you are launching the pod on the node where the host path exists. I am assuming `testserver.local` and `test-server` are the same.

HTH

Comment: Files have rw permssions. 
RStudio doesn't use that path. That's why I redirected it to /tmp. And yes, I am launching the pod where hostpath exists.@Faheem

Comment: Does is `rw` for all? Who is the owner? What user are running with inside the container. Configuration you have is working for me. It's something your environment.

Comment: I resolved this issue. "Also, make sure you are launching the pod on the node where the host path exists. I am assuming testserver.local and test-server are the same."" This point was the thing.

Comment: I have a question- What is the best way to mount a directory if testserver.local and test-server are 2 different servers? Which method is the best?

Comment: Ideally, the storage should be separate from the nodes hosting containers. Think NFS or data disks. If you want to use the local disk, consider using `nodeAffinity` and `nodeSelector` like attributes for consistency. See the answer of this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/60283134/54354

Answer (score 0):

Does you PVC make use of the PV you created? Check it with

```
kubectl get pvc
```

Try adding a label to the pv and use a `matchLabels` selector to make sure the PVC actually consumes the PV you just created:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-volume-rsp
  labels:
    name: pv-volume-rsp  # Added
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/rstudio"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-rsp
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: pv-volume-rsp  # Added
```